# How to perform data augmentation on a set of images and its masks in keras?

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

I want to perform the augmentations of both my original images and its segmented masks, but I always end up with some error like:

1. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
2. Unable to expand 3 ranked image to a 4 ranked one

Here is my code:

```py
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=5)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

seed = 1
images= []
masks= []

for image in glob.glob('../data/images/*.jpg'):
    images.append(cv.imread(image))
for image in glob.glob('../data/masks/*.jpg'):
    masks.append(cv.imread(image))

images= np.array(images)
masks= np.array(masks)

for image in images:
    image_datagen.fit(image[np.newaxis], augment=True, seed=seed)

for image in masks:
    mask_datagen.fit(image[np.newaxis], augment=True, seed=seed)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow(images, seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(masks, seed=seed)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

id = 0
for images, masks in train_generator:
    for image, mask in zip(images, masks):
        cv.imwrite('../data/aug_images/images/' + str(id), image)
        cv.imwrite('../data/aug_images/masks/' + str(id), mask)
        id += 1
```

Can someone correct me where I am going wrong? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I have a set of images and it's maskings. I want to obtain the same augmentation/transformation for both of them.

Comment: How is that two different errors occur? Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: 1st error occurs when I open a list of images that I from a directory and pass it to the flow function. 2nd error occurs when I pass only one image. It is expecting a 4D shape instead of a 3D shape image I think.

Comment: As for the second error, the input array must have a shape of `(n_samples, img_width, img_height, num_channels)`. So you must expand the single image, e.g. with `img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how do I solve the first error? Like I want to pass on all the (images and masks) from the directory and then store the augmented (images and masks) in some other directory. Can you re-write the code and help me?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code that produces the first error? Also please provide the full stacktrace (i.e. traceback) of the error as well.